# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' Python

Tags: python, csv, enums, hashtable

I'm trying to extract the column number of a column using csv dict and give that as an input to countt. However, it gives me an error saying `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' Python`. Here's the part of my code that's been causing me troubles.

```
indexes = [i for i,x in enumerate(all_fieldnames) if x == barcode]
countt = [rec[indexes] for rec in tsv_data]
```

I'd really appreciate if you tell me how to fix it.

I've seen many similar questions on stackoverflow before posting here, but none of them helped.

Comment: Is `rec` a dictionary? You are passing in a *list* of indices (`indexes` is a list).

Comment: what you want to do with by `rec[indexes]`?

Comment: If you really want to use a list-like structure as a key in a Python `dict`, then use a tuple. To convert list `xs` to a tuple, use `tuple(xs)`. The reason why the developers of Python wanted to disallow `list` is because it is mutable. If we change a `list` object which we previously used as a dict key, should the key also change? If yes, it would be hard to implement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing in *a list* of indices (`indexes` is that list). Moreover, `rec` is a dictionary (presumably you are using `DictReader`) so you should use keys, not indexes.

If `barcode` contains the field name you are looking for you can just use:

```
countt = [rec[barcode] for rec in tsv_data]
```

Comment: maybe `countt = [rec[barcode] for rec in tsv_data]`... that doesn't seams a litteral string

Comment: @Micheled'Amico: indeed; although I am not sure that was the intention either.

Comment: Trust me! I tried this before and it didn't work! It works great now. Thank you very much!